# Эффективная работа с БД для большого RPS

Tags: java, база-данных, асинхронность

Начал изучать джаву, решил сделать для примера простой REST API сервер, у него простые задачи:

- Принять запрос, сходить в БД узнать есть ли у пользователя привелегии на такой запрос
- Сходить в БД ещё раз, взять статью или создать новую
- Отрендерить ответ и отправить пользователю

Как видно, сервер в основном общается с БД, а сам по себе делает мало работы.

Мой вопрос о том, как обрабатывать максимальное количество запросов этим сервером.

Я не могу нагуглить ничего полезного про асинхронное взаимодействие в java, все предлагают только создавать треды, но меня интересует производительность, я хочу обрабатывать новые запросы пока жду ответа от БД и если для каждого запроса буду создавать новый тред, то закончатся ресурсы ОС, а если создать пулл тредов, то все равно можно попасть в ситуацию когда сервер не делает ничего полезного, а просто ждет пока 100 тредов получат ответ от БД, в это время ничего не делая с остальными запросами.

В nodejs нет такой проблемы из-за event loop, но я решил попробовать java, потому что у него хороший ООП и типизация. Какой подход используют java разработчики для эффективной обработки таких задач? И как вообще общаться с БД асинхронно? Если я что-то не правильно понимаю в тредах, поправьте меня пожалуйста

Comment: Если честно, то для построения апи я бы выбрал c#, асинхронные запросы там являются нормой. Не знаю, как это в java работает, наверняка что то тоже имеется на этот счёт. Но если вас интересует прямо производительность на максималке, подумайте о кеше, например, чтобы не лазать в бд вообще для критически важных запросов.

Comment: Но вообще о производительности стоит думать, если у вас с ней есть проблемы. Выбирать язык программирования чисто из соображений производительности это тупиковый путь. Можно написать производительный сервер на чем угодно.

Comment: @tym32167 БД это просто пример. Это могут быть запросы к микросервису, чтение файлов, чтение изменяющихся данных или что угодно ещё. Меня интересует jvm платформа и конкретно java

Comment: в явном или неявном виде потоки всё равно будут создаваться. Кто-то же должен ждать, пока запрос в БД отработает и просигнализировать об этом. Возьмите Spring Web и работайте через него. Высокоэффективные connection pool + thread pool будут у вас из коробки, не нужно будет думать "а как же остальные запросы". По остальным примерам - первое, что приходит в голову - `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`

Comment: там где есть луп там всегда есть проблемы с производительностью. асинхронные запросы не решают эту проблему.

Comment: @kami потоки конечно будут. А как работает spring web?  Как именно он решает мою задачу? Приходит запрос, мы его обрабатываем, делаем запрос к API и что в этот момент происходит?

Comment: Алгоритм найти ответ такой: на https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks выбирайте нужный вам тест (multiple queries подойдет), и смотрите в графе Lng java. Далее смотрите используемые технологии и идиоматические для тех технологий способы создания приложений. В лидерах [wizzardo](https://github.com/wizzardo/webery) и [vert.x](https://vertx.io/), которые используют event loop подобно nodejs. Ключевые слова для поиска еще `actor model`, `akka`.

Comment: Еще ключевые слова для поиска `C10K` и `epoll`.

Comment: @RomanKonoval спасибо за полезные ссылки и ключевые слова

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже вашу проблему лучше всего будет решить с помощью *реактивного программирования*.

В Java для этого есть достаточно много библиотек и фреймворков (*Project Reactor, RxJava, Vert.x, Spring WebFlux* и т.д.)

Простой пример реактивного REST на WebFlux с запросом к базе через SpringData+R2DBC можно найти, скажем, [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/565752/)

Также много примеров, статей и документации по реактивному программированию, библиотекам и фреймворкам можно найти через гугл

Comment: Похоже что так. Спасибо за ответ, очень полезные ссылки на конкретные проекты. А какие асинхронные фреймворки самые популярные? Может быть 1-2 какие-нибудь. Много вкладок открыл для изучения, пока что немного опасаюсь что популярен WebFlux и что там все построено на анотациях, а я бы хотел что-то менее магическое. Но это на первый взгляд, может просто показалось. В любом случае, ещё раз спасибо за полезный ответ

Comment: К сожалению не смогу подсказать, какие из них наиболее популярные. Подозреваю что у всех из них есть свои плюсы и минусы, которые учитываются для конкретного проекта.
Лучше искать в интернете, например много статей [вроде таких](https://medium.com/priceline-labs/choosing-a-reactive-framework-for-the-jvm-ec66f6cde552), делать прототипы и бэнчмарки, которые покажут насколько те или иные фреймворки/библиотеки подходит конкретно для Ваших целей.